# WCF request doesn't flow via asp.net pipeline

Tags: asp.net, wcf, integrated-pipeline-mode

I have a WCF service hosted in an asp.net application.

Here's the service (shortened):

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
[ServiceContract(Name = Name, Namespace = Namespace)]
[ServiceBehavior(Name = Name, Namespace = Namespace)]
public class WcfMaintenanceFacade {...}
```

Here's hosting:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("entity/maintenance/5.20", new ServiceHostFactory(), typeof(WcfMaintenanceFacade)));
```

And here's relevant config section:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

My service instantiates, the requests are coming in, and event `HttpContext.Current` is not empty.

There are two (major, for me) issues that I can't solve:

1. `HttpContext.Current.Session` is empty
2. Global.asax's `Application_BeginRequest` is never called

And yes, from the call stack it seems like the request is going through WCF activation pipeline, not ASP.net pipeline. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should use `OperationContext` when it comes to wcf execution pipeline. Why would a WCF service use a global.asax? Isn't it specific to web applications?

Comment: If your service is dependent on Session, you could implement reliable session on your service. please read - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733136(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm integrating a WCF service into a legacy application that already relies heavily on asp.net pipeline.

Comment: the processing pipeline are different for these two technologies. So routing a WCF message to ASP.Net pipeline is not desirable. To enable session in WCF you have to enable reliable session , but how this is going to communicate with ASP.Net session, I'm not sure. If you find a way around inform me, meanwhile I'm also looking for a solution.

Comment: from MSDN - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040(v=vs.110).aspx

In Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) applications, a session correlates a group of messages into a conversation. WCF sessions are different than the session object available in ASP.NET applications, support different behaviors, and are controlled in different ways.

Comment: Processing pipeline does not have to be different (for example, in Classic pipeline mode the requests to WCF go through asp.net pipeline), and that's exactly what I need.

Comment: Maybe you have google it already (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sajay/archive/2006/08/03/687361.aspx), but anyway.

Comment: @Mimas Unfortunately, I've already seen that and gone through it, no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the answer is simple (and, well, obvious):

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

Yes. RAMMFAR.

Answer (score 4):

1. About the session, you handle it with OperationContext.Current.RequestContext instead of HttpContext.Current.Session.

> HttpContext: Current is always null when accessed from within a WCF
>   service. Use
>   T:System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.RequestContext instead.

Read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx

2. Application_BeginRequest are used by ASP.Net applications, but WCF works different from common web applications, thus BeginRequest could not be hit on each request.

> The ASP.NET HTTP runtime handles ASP.NET requests but does not
>   participate in the processing of requests destined for WCF services
>   .... he WCF Service Model intercepts messages addressed to WCF
>   services and routes them through the WCF transport/channel stack

So, your problem can be related to this issue. This information is also available at the same link.

Hope it helps with your questions.

Comment: Unfortunately, both points are irrelevant to my cause. First of all, I need access to asp.net `Session`, because the whole application is written relying on it. Second, it _is_ possible to route WCF messages through asp.net pipeline (for example, with classic mode and wildcard script mapping), but I am surprised I can't achieve the same behaviour under integrated mode.

Answer (score 0):

For me it is clear that these two technologies are not supposed to be working in the same application, and that's why they have two different pipelines. Service by the nature is an isolated thing. Now you just try to find a workaround, relying on the fact they both work on same IIS.

I would recommend you rather start from the goals, from what you want to achieve. If you need new service-like functionality integrated into native ASP.NET application you can

1) use ASMX services (will give you SAOP if you need it) and/or page methods

2) try to integrate WEB API in case you need JSON service.

Comment: I need SOAP. Current implementation uses ASMX, but I want to get more control over the service and contract behaviour.

Comment: Also: if they are not supposed to be working in the same application, where does `AspNetCompatibilityRequirements` come from?

Comment: Ok. Maybe you'r right. Did you try checking at runtime (``ServiceHostingEnvironment.AspNetCompatibilityEnabled`` property), if your mode really set to proper value?
As I can see here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.aspnetcompatibilityrequirementsattribute.aspx) MS says, you should get an access to the session.

Comment: Yep, I know what MS says, and still: `ServiceHostingEnvironment.AspNetCompatibilityEnabled` is `true`, `HttpContext.Current` is *not* `null`, and `HttpContext.Current.Session` *is* `null`. That's exactly my problem.

Comment: But Serg Rogovtsev, in Application_BeginRequest you still don't have your session created, it must hit the Session_Start first in order to create a session. I think you are trying to access the session too early to the global.asax flux. Put a break point in Session_Start and check out if your session object is still null.

Comment: @RicardoPontual `Application_BeginRequest` is **not** hit, and I am checking for session inside the service itself.